# How can I list the content of a source folder from a React application client-side?

Tags: reactjs, readdir

I have a small React application that links routes to specific Markdown files located under `/src/pages/`. Trying to build a table of content automatically, I need to list the content of `/src/pages/` client-side. Here is what I tried:

```jsx
new Promise((resolve, reject) => glob('**/*.md', (error, files) => {
  if (error) {
    reject(error);
  }
  resolve(files);
})).then(files => console.log(files));
```

But `readdir` isnt' available in the browser.

Comment: I don't think its possible yet. Client side (browser apis) are not allowed to access system files.

Comment: @RonnWilder How about `import`? I can't recall where exactly, but I've seen somewhere an import for files client-side. Something like that: `import Pages from './pages/'; Pages['home.md']`. For reference, I import aforementioned Markdown files using `import` to feed them to `ReactMarkdown`. https://github.com/angrybacon/doomsday-wiki/blob/master/src/components/page.js#L53-L55